# How do I stop Ninject for WebApi failing on "var kernel = new StandardKernel();"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, ninject

I just installed Ninject.MVC5 into my solution (I have an MVC project and a WebApi project in there and I wanted Ninject for both).

Then I installed WebApiContrib.IoC.Ninject to build on the previous install so that I could use Ninject in the WebApi package.

Then I updated the packages (because NuGet showed updates to install - even though I had updated the packages directly prior to installing Ninject).

I tried running my WebApi project but it failed on `var kernel = new StandardKernel();`  in `NinjectWebCommon.CreateKernel()` with this error:

```
An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Ninject.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Having read several answers on here and contemplated certain relatively complex solutions I tried one more thing which I will share in the Answer in case it helps anyone else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed WebApiContrib.IoC.Ninject from the WebApi project (via NuGet: Manage and then untick to remove) and then added it back.

Project runs and behaves as expected, and no updates are required after adding WebApiContrib.IoC.Ninject back in to WebApi project.

The update that NuGet identified as required overwrote/broke something that was fixed by this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add the package **Microsoft.Aspnet.Mvc** from Nuget.

Solved for me.

In my case, MVC4 for Framework 4.0 and Visual Studio 2017